# How to add multiple value field in webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to add a file field called picture to a webform, and Want it to be a multiple value field to allow users to upload more than a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Webform Multiple File Upload](https://drupal.org/project/webform_multifile) allows user to upload multiple files on a webform and you can also limit the number of files, see the below image.

[image]